# Font Awesome Convert into a number in android

Tags: android

Here i have to create a one button in which i want to write string as well as create a icon .
I used the font-awesome and font-tello but in both of them i facing a problem in out put the the icon is converted into a number format any one give solution.

Thank You in advance..

## MainActivity.java

```
Typeface newFont = null;
Button cameraBtn = null;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
cameraBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
newButton = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/fonta.ttf");
cameraBtn.setTypeface(newButton);
cameraBtn.setText(R.string.icon);
}
```

## string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="app_name">TestApplication</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="action_search">Search</string>
<string name="icon">&#xf1c9;</string>
</resources>
```

## Activity_Main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#151415" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/button3"
android:layout_width="120dp"
android:layout_height="75dp"
android:layout_weight="0.335"
android:background="#666666"
android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Also i putted the font-awesm.ttf into assets/fonts ..

### Output

"2131099652 Text"

Comment: Use a textview with a drawableLeft and a background to match your button, then set clickable to true

Comment: sorry but i am not understand what sir you tell can you please explain sir..

Comment: you might want to try this library: https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify

Comment: this one might also be interesting: https://github.com/DayS/EnhancedEditText

Comment: Both is very nice but here i dont finds the icon that i need thank you

Comment: Sorry read this really quick in the car, was thinking you were trying to set an actual drawable as the icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution

```
camerabtn.append("TEXT HERE");
```

Thank You All Of you for Solutions..